# Function prototypes and argument coercion

Tags: c++, function-prototypes

From my C++ textbook

> an important feature of function prototypes is argument coercion
>   - i.e, forcing argument to the appropriate types specified by the parameter declaration. For example, a program can call a function with
>   an integer argument, even though the function prototype specifies a
>   double argument - the function will still work correctly.

So i've tryied

```
#include <iostream>

// void foo(double);

void foo(double a) {

   std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;
}

int main (void){

   int a = 1;
   std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;
   foo(a);

   return 0;
}
```

and with **or without prototype** it prints correctly first 4 then
(inside function) 8.

Is my compiler that checks function definition in absence of
prototypes (that may be not strict C++ standard, but
useful too) or I have missed something?

Comment: What is the confusion here?  You have an `int` in `main`, and a `double` in `foo`; they are different sizes (on your platform).

Comment: my confusion comes from my textbook statement since I didn't used prototypes

Comment: I think confusion is about the `prototype` word. You understand `prototype` as `declaration`, but `prototype` is the signature of a function, and here, you have the `prototype` directly in the  `definition` of your function and the previous `declaration` is useless.

Comment: @AntiClimacus the code posted was the last test done. Previously i've put function definition below main. However i don't understand one thing: here you say line 5 `void foo(double a) {` works as prototype? PS. In the end i'm thinking here my book was not as accurate as elsewhere.

Comment: @LucaBraglia: read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration and keep in mind that a `prototype` is included in both declaration and definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is as it should be here. Consider what you are outputting with your `sizeof` call. You are outputting the size of the variable. Now what you have to understand is when you pass `a` to your function `foo`, `a` is implicitly converted to a `double`. The `double` has the same value as the `int`, but they are different types. The size of the `int` is 4 bytes and the size of the `double` is 8 bytes on your architecture.

Basically, what your textbooks means when it says the compiler will force arguments to the appropriate types specified by the parameter declaration is that it will look at your `int a` and find what it would be as a double (It would be 4 in both cases). The compiler does this because it sees that the function `foo` requires a `double` but `foo` is getting an `int`. It does not change the type of `a` in your main function. `a` in `main` is always an `int` and `a` in your `foo` function is always a `double`.

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast
for more on implicit conversion.

Comment: to add to this. `static_cast < double >`, instead of implicit conversions (up-cast), would make the compiler understand the up-cast, and hence no complains. This explicit up-cast, would resolve the warning.

Answer (score 1):

What actually happens here is that the compiler realizes that `foo` takes a `double` argument, and converts the `int` argument to `double`. The output shows that `double` is 8 bytes in this particular system, and `int` is 4 bytes - both of which is pretty ordinary. Note that `a` inside `foo` isn't THE SAME `a` as in `main`. They are different things, even if they are called the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The function `foo` instantiates a new temporary value, also happens to be called `a` which is of type double using the `int` you passed to it. Then, you are printing the size of this new temporary double. The size is 8, because on your platform, a double is 8.

Answer (score 1):

The next slide from your textbook slides clearly explains what your complier is doing. Check it out: 
 Sometimes, argument values that do not correspond precisely to the
parameter types in the function prototype can be converted by the
compiler to the proper type before the function is called.
 These conversions occur as specified by C++’s promotion rules. 
 The promotion rules indicate how to convert between types without
losing data.
 An int can be converted to a double without changing its value.
 However, a double converted to an int truncates the fractional
part of the double value.
 Keep in mind that double variables can hold numbers of much
greater magnitude than int variables, so the loss of data may be
considerable.